# 'waitForPageToLoad'/'waitForElementPresent' - how use in Selenium2? (C#)

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Guys, I have problem with waitForPageToLoad condtion. I'm using C# with Nunit, and I don't know exactly what I should use instead of 'waitForPageToLoad'/'waitForElementPresent'. Maybe someone knows how I can use 'waitForPageToLoad'/'waitForElementPresent' in Selenium 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use FindElement() for something on the new page. Wrap in in a loop that will keep trying until the element is found, with a maximum wait.

```
// pseudocode WebElement wait_for_element(By locator)
while (!timeout) {
  try {
    return driver.FindElement(locator);
  } catch (Exception) {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
  }
  // check for timeout here
}
throw new NoSuchElementException("Timeout waiting for "+locator);
```

Comment: Hi Randall, thanks for you response, it is exactly what I can use!

Answer (score 0):

```
ISelenium selenium = new DefaultSelenium( "localhost", 4444, "*chrome", "
    http://localhost/UrlOfAppToTest/" );
selenium.WaitForPageToLoad( "30000" );
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Hi Charlie - not exactly: below you can find my code:                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.skyscanner.net?ncr=1");
            IWebElement query = driver.FindElement(By.Id("country_selection_box"));
            query.Click();
            var country =
                driver.FindElement(
                    By.CssSelector("html body.lang-pl div#user_country_panel_popup div.bd div.content select"));
            country.SendKeys("Great Britain");
            country.Click();
            country.Clear();

Comment: Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)); //This line currently is my timeout, the problem is that script always waits 10 seconds, in selenium 1 I had something like e.g. selenium.waitForPageToLoad("3000"). Thanks that the script was more "intelligence" - waited when the page was fully loaded (sometimes it was 3 seconds, another time 9 seconds). I found one solution on googlegroups: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=549 but here I have to do my own class.

Comment: I hope that now my question is more clearly. However you are uses one interesting thing, I thinkng about ISelenium - in which library I can find it? 

            
            //select of language

            IWebElement jezyk = driver.FindElement(By.Id("selLanguage"));
            jezyk.Click();
            var specificLanguage =
                driver.FindElement(

Comment: By.CssSelector(
                        "html body.lang-pl div#skyscanner-doc.yui-t-skyscanner div#hd div#hd_personalization div.language select#selLanguage option"));
            specificLanguage.SendKeys("English");
            specificLanguage.Click();
            specificLanguage.Clear();

Answer (score 0):

You could use a explicit wait method to wait for your action/page to load.
With that you can specify a condition to be met, and when it is met your test will continue.

See link for more details:
[Selenium HQ, explicit wait](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.html)